# how to use product function if some range cells are blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to multiple three cell values after subtract from 100%,I used product function and also tried aggregate function.i get error when if one of cell is blank.need subtract c cloumns value f colum n value and i column value from 100% then multiple.please note sometimes one of c ,f of i values can be blank.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the error - unless do you have a space or some sort of text in F3?

Comment: c ,f,I columns contain above formula,=IFERROR(E3/D3,"")

Comment: Well those `""` are your problem :-) `1 - ""` isn't going to work. I'd make that zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435073/how-to-use-product-function-if-some-range-cells-are-blanks#comment106912363_60435073) stated, the only way you get this error is if there is a formula that returns a null string or space in the field.

To get around that we just need to use IFERROR to deal with the resulting error:

```
=PRODUCT(IFERROR(1-CHOOSE({1,2,3},C3,F3,I3),1))
```

Depending on ones version of Excel this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Or since there is only three just use three IFERRORs and multiply the results:

```
=IFERROR(1-C3,1)*IFERROR(1-F3,1)*IFERROR(1-I3,1)
```

This is just a normal formula.

---

A third option is to return `0` instead of `""` in your original formula:

```
=IFERROR(E3/D3,0)
```

Then format the cell `%;%;;` and it will hide the `0`

Comment: ^^^ 3rd option ^^^